# Replay Subject does not trigger async pipe if it is initialized with the subscribe shorthand

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm wondering why a replay subject that is created with the subscribe shorthand does not trigger the async pipeline when the next method is called.

When I do it the following way. Everything works fine

```
export class Container implements OnInit {
  public companyDetailSubject$: ReplaySubject<CompanyDetail> = new ReplaySubject<CompanyDetail>(1);

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.companyControllerService.getUserCompany().subscribe((company) => this.companyDetailSubject$.next(company));



  private updateCompanyName(newCompanyName: string) {
    this.companyControllerService.updateCompany({...this.companyDetail, name: newCompanyName})
      .pipe(
          tap(updatedCompany => {
            this.companyDetailSubject$.next(updatedCompany); // This works and triggers the async pipeline. The child component will get the new company
          }),
      )
      .subscribe();
  }
```

Then in the HTML I pass the replay subject to a child component with the async pipe

```
    <child-component
            [companyDetail]="companyDetailSubject$ | async">
    </child-component>
```

And If I setup the component like this it works on the initial page load. But when next is called from the updateCompanyName method it does not trigger the async pipeline and the child component does not get the new company name. And I would like to understand why it breaks when I use the subscribe shorthand to emit the first value for the CompanyDetailSubject

```
export class Container implements OnInit {
  public companyDetailSubject$: ReplaySubject<CompanyDetail> = new ReplaySubject<CompanyDetail>(1);

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    // this is the only difference to the working example
this.companyControllerService.getUserCompany().subscribe(this.companyDetailSubject$);



  private updateCompanyName(newCompanyName: string) {
    this.companyControllerService.updateCompany({...this.companyDetail, name: newCompanyName})
      .pipe(
          tap(updatedCompany => {
            this.companyDetailSubject$.next(updatedCompany); // This next call will not work! It does not trigger the async pipeline
          }),
      )
      .subscribe();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The short hand call `subscribe(this.companyDetailSubject$);` causes the `companyDetailSubject$` to be completed (after the caller is completed).

That why you'll never get any new value.